# Как использовать пользовательскую форму несколько раз?

Tags: excel, vba

#### Доброго времени суток.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли в **VBA** использовать одну и ту же UserForm несколько раз?

Нужно сделать так, чтобы пользователь мог вводить в TextBox правильные ответы. По типу карточек для изучения слов.

Мне удалось сделать так, чтобы пользователь вводил понятие и правильный ответ к нему вручную и эти данные попадали в двумерный массив, но вот как сделать так, чтобы дальше можно было с этими данными работать не совсем понимаю.

По моей задумке, после заполнения пользователем карточек, его перенаправляет на другую форму, где расположено два TextBox. В одном из них появляется понятие, во втором пользователь должен дать ответ. И так, пока пользователю не надоест и он не закроет форму. При чём форма не должна меняться: пользователю высветилось слово -> пользователь дал ответ -> программа обработала и дала следующее слово.

Заранее, **спасибо**.

Comment: Форму можно использовать и для ввода данных, и для работы с этими данными: при открытии формы передавать ей какой-либо параметр или флаг. Например: False - ввод данных, True - работа с сохраненными данными

Answer (score 0):

Зачем тебе двумерный массив? Открой таблицу Excel, создай там в одной колонке первую сторону карточки, в другой — другую. Затем открой там VBA и создай там UserForm. Возьми случайную строку, введи данные из неё в TextBox. После проверки ответа пользователя по нажатию кнопки возьми другую строку и забей из неё данные в TextBox. Никаких массивов не надо. Лишние заморочки. И что значит использовать несколько раз? Просто добавь кнопку и вставь в неё код на VBA проверяющий ответ, отображающий его правильность и вводящий новое слово.